# php payment gateway security issue

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway

I have a test payment gateway that I use that in localhost environment.

I wrote a function that checks if the hostname is localhost and other test hosts then proceed to redirect to that gateway.

**Now the issue is that a person from production env used that test gateway to buy a product.**

**My BankController:**

```
  function request($bankName, $price,$user = null)
{
    switch (strtoupper($bankName)) {
        case Bank::MELLAT:
            return $this->redirectTo(new Mellat(), $price,$user);



       //ZARINPAL is my test gateway
        case Bank::ZARINPAL:
            if (is_testing_host())
                return $this->redirectTo(new Zarinpal(), $price,$user);



        case Bank::SAMAN:
            return $this->redirectTo(new Saman(), $price,$user);

        case Bank::SAMANKISH:
            return $this->redirectTo(new SamanKish(), $price,$user);
        // other banks here...
    }

    throw new \Exception('Gateway not found');
}
```

**is_testing_host function :**

```
 function is_testing_host()
{
 return in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['localhost', '127.0.0.1','::1'])
 || request()->getHost() == 'site.test';
}
```

**Html choose gateway :**

```
<select class="form-control" style="padding:5px;" name="bank" id="bank">
     @if(is_testing_host())
          <option value="zarinpal" selected="selected">Zarinpal</option>
     @else
          <option value="saman">درگاه پرداخت سامان کیش</option>
     @endif
</select>
```

**My test :**

I changed the select value to zarinpal(test gateway) from inspect elemnt then i clicked submit btn.
It sent zarinpal but redirected to another gateway.(seems like there is no bug)

can someone help me find how did he used that gateway ?!

Comment: Not a security expert, but forging the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable could be one explanation. Another could be that you are using a local reverse proxy, which could lead to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` always being `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. Altering the HTML is only an addition, but surely not the main problem. -- Btw., please use curly braces for your `if` statements, especially when they are important: `if(is_testing_host()) { return ...; }`

Comment: What Laravel is this? I would never use `@` anymore its stupid, just use `??` like this `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? []` (for PHP7.1+) but that does not answer the question, its more like a suggestion. You need to set up trusted proxies and use Laravel to get the IP: `request()->getClientIp()` I would also disable everything thats not meant to be running on production server using either ServiceProvider or some kind of configuration. Also NEVER TRUST CLIENT. Use environment local, test, production instead like pros do https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: This question is too broad as all anyone can do is guess what happened